# Power Automate: Extract info from excel file into sharepoint list, then save excel file as attachment?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow where I extract data from excel files that have been saved to a specific sharepoint "upload" folder, and then populate a list with the information in those excel files.

What i'd like to add is to:

1. Upload the excel file as an attachment to the list item (ideally with a standard name concatenating the title and current date)
2. Delete the excel file from the upload folder

At the end of the day there would be no files in the upload folder but the files would have been shared as attachments to their respective list items.

The upload of the data from the files is working.  I just can't figure out how to add that specific file as an attachment to the item and delete the file from the original sharepoint upload folder.

If possible, I'd like to rename the file as "Title - Date" in the sharepoint list item.

Answer (score 0):

To upload the excel file as an attachment to the list item, you can use the “Add attachment” action in Power Automate.Here’s an example of how you can do it:

1.Add "Get file content"

1.add an “Add attachment” action to attach the excel file to the newly created item.

2.In the “Add attachment” action, specify the name of the attachment by concatenating the title and current date you can add this expression: utcNow('dd-MM-yyyy')

3.To delete the excel file from the upload folder,In the “Delete file” action, specify the path of the file you want to delete.
[image]